# From propietary format to c++ classes

Tags: c++, c, parsing, format, translation

Given an input like this (USER DEFINED FORMAT):

```
type dog<
int years
char[] name
>
```

How can I generate 2 or more differents files like these:

```
file1.c
------------
struct dog{
int years
char name
}

file2.cpp
-------------
class dog{
int years
string name
%get and set methods
}
```

Is a parser generator like flex and bison the best way? Or are there better way?

Comment: If the user-defined format has well-defined lexical and grammar rules, flex/bison would be appropriate. If, on the other hand, the user-defined format doesn't fit nicely into the lexical and LALR(1) buckets, a handmade parser would be the option of last resort.

Comment: user defined format has well defined lexical and grammar rules.
If I use flex/bison, I am obliged to work in c, right?

Comment: I've written a similar program in python that generated c++ code from xml dtd document. I don't know whether it is better or worse than some other way. Of course, in that case a parser already existed.

Comment: Both flex and bison have options to generate C++ code. See their respective documentation for more information.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express my concern about c  in a proper way. I think that writing a format translator using C is not a great idea because strings manipulation in C  is not so easy. Whit flex and bison I can only write a C parser right?

Comment: As I wrote: with the appropriate options, flex and bison will generate a C++ parser, instead of the default parser.

Comment: ok I got it, thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the complextity of your language and the transformations you intend.

**Option 1: hand-crafted ad-hoc processing**

If your transformations are simple and mostly convert some tokens from your source language into the target language (e.g "type" into "struct" and "<>" into "{}"), you could think of a hand-crafted parsing using string operations or [regexes](https://regex101.com/r/eS4kK7/1) using [`std::regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

But this is not sufficient here:  you must identify statements in your source langage to generate semi-column separated c and c++ statements. Furhtermore, you must related the `[]` to the right element.  Furthermore, to generate correct getter/setter your code must get understanding of the statement content.

So yes, here you'll need a lexer and a parser.

**Option 2: hand-crafted parser**

For "simple" languages, you could craft easily [a recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). What does "simple" mean ?  It means that the language which can be described with a LL(1) grammar. Without entering now too much in compiler theory, it's more or less languages where one token ahead uniquely determine which grammar construct you have.

Note that you have a very simple calculator example designed this way in the "*C++ Programming language*" from Bjarne Stroustrup.

**Option 3: use a compiler generator**

While lexical scanners and recursive descent parsers are relatively easy to code, it's still somehow reinventing the wheel.  And for languages which are not LL(1) compliant, you have no other choice than using a compiler generator.

Flex/bison is then a very reasonable and widely supported choice. But you have to become familiar with its logic, grammar files, and code templates.  It's not something that you could master in a couple of hours.

If you have to support a custom language professionally, it's really worth the investment.  If it's a small project, the learning curve could play against you.

**Option 4: lightweight boost alternative**

Another, lighter, approach could be to use [boost spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), which bases itself on c++ and is easier to learn: you express the grammar rule directly in C++.  There are too main components: [Lex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/tutorials/lexer_quickstart2.html) for lexical scanner and [Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) for parsers.

It's ok for small to medium parsers (like a data definition language), but it has [some serious limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438532/3723423) if you have a full language.  And by the way, as far as I know, it's limited to LL(k) grammars.